# string to []int golang

Tags: golang

```go
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strconv"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  a := "1 2 3 4 5 6"
  var lol []int
  for _, v := range strings.Split(a, " ") {
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(v)
    lol = append(lol, num)
  }
  fmt.Println(lol)
}
```

есть ли более короткий способ?, скажем как в питоне:

```py
a = '1 2 3 4 5 6'
lol = list(map(int, a.split()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из коробки в Golang нет пакетов для функционального программирования.

На коленке получилось вот что склепать

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    a := "1 2 3 4 5 6"
    lol, _ := TransformE(strings.Split(a, " "), strconv.Atoi)
    fmt.Println(lol)
}

func TransformE[T any, U any](input []T, operator func(T) (U, error)) ([]U, error) {
    result := make([]U, len(input))
    var err error
    for i, t := range input {
        result[i], err = operator(t)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Можно добавить трансформатор без ошибки

```
func Transform[T any, U any](input []T, operator func(T) U) []U {
    result := make([]U, len(input))
    for i, t := range input {
        result[i] = operator(t)
    }
    return result
}
```

До кучи добавить фильтрацию

```
func Keep[T any](input []T, operator func(T) bool) []T {
    result := []T{}
    for _, t := range input {
        if operator(t) {
            result = append(result, t)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func KeepE[T any](input []T, operator func(T) (bool, error)) ([]T, error) {
    result := []T{}
    for _, t := range input {
        v, err := operator(t)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if v {
            result = append(result, t)
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

и редукцию...

Можно много что написать, но это будет уже другая история.

Отвечая же на ваш вопрос - можно как в Python, но не средствами стандартной библиотеки.